# How can I modify default page for UV4L streaming server at Raspberry Pi?

Tags: webrtc, raspberry-pi2

I had a Raspberry Pi 2 with camera, and followed this page to install a [webrtc streaming server](http://www.linux-projects.org/uv4l/installation/)

It worked great, and I was able to view the default page when I typed in http://*raspberry*:8080/. It looks like this:
[default landing page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5Yhz.png)
[image]

I am wondering how I can modify this default page? I cannot find the folder containing the www files. Can anyone give me the path to the files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The html pages are embeded inside the library `/usr/lib/uv4l/libserver.so`.
It is possible to extract the html pages using :

```
strings /usr/lib/uv4l/libserver.so | awk '/<html>/,/<\/html>/ {print}'
```

Then to modify the default page, without the source code, you will need to patch the binary file. This could be really tricky.